# Warn on missing Spring properties

Tags: java, spring

We use Spring, and a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to wire our properties. Currently, we have set `setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders` to `true` which lets the app just continue if a property is missing.

While I think it's better to just crash the app, we find this to risky at the moment, so we would like a intermediate solution: warn on missing properties.

We would like a log message on warn or error level that a property is missing, but the app should still do a best effort to start.

Is this possible in Spring 4 and Java 8?

Comment: it would be nice to share some code.. that way we have a clearer picture of what you're saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the source of the [PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java), specifically the processProperties method:

```
protected void processProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactoryToProcess,
        final ConfigurablePropertyResolver propertyResolver) throws BeansException {

    propertyResolver.setPlaceholderPrefix(this.placeholderPrefix);
    propertyResolver.setPlaceholderSuffix(this.placeholderSuffix);
    propertyResolver.setValueSeparator(this.valueSeparator);

    StringValueResolver valueResolver = new StringValueResolver() {
        @Override
        public String resolveStringValue(String strVal) {
            String resolved = (ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders ?
                    propertyResolver.resolvePlaceholders(strVal) :
                    propertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(strVal));
            if (trimValues) {
                resolved = resolved.trim();
            }
            return (resolved.equals(nullValue) ? null : resolved);
        }
    };

    doProcessProperties(beanFactoryToProcess, valueResolver);
}
```

You can see that it contains a simple check.
You can also see that the method is *protected*.
The solution then would be to create your own PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer subclass, which overrides the method. 
It contains exactly the same code... but logs a warning.

So

```
String resolved = (ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders ?
        propertyResolver.resolvePlaceholders(strVal) :
        propertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(strVal));
```

Then becomes

```
String resolved = (ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders ?
        propertyResolver.resolvePlaceholders(strVal) :
        propertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(strVal));
if(strVal.equals(resolved)) {
    LOG.warn("Property "+ strVal+ " could not be found");
```

Maybe not the easiest solution...

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Turned out that there are many strings being resolved (mainly package names, empty strings, etc) by the spring framework, so I had to filter that out. I added a regex check for spring property placeholders